# How to get the ID of the current content

Tags: php, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, collapsable, impresspages

I am trying to modify the 'Collapsable and Tabs' widget to a Bootstrap one but I am stuck on finding out the IP of a whole collapsable/tab group/container.

It's needed to set a unique ID to each group like this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo $widgetId ?>">
  [Tab 1]
  [Tab 2]
  ...
</div>
```

Already tried to check out examples but I am stuck.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
var collapseIn = $('.panel-group').find('div.collapse.in')[0];
if (collapseIn) console.log($(collapseIn).attr('id'));
```

Example here [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/davit/12/edit)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. 
I just get this error, now:  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)

Comment: I solved this looking at the Accordion widget where the IDs are called from within the php.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this looking at the Accordion widget where the IDs are called from within the php.